# pulumi retrieve an object or array of configs stored

Tags: pulumi

When making a call to `new pulumi.Config('someName')` I would like to get an array of secrets that are under `someName:aValue`.

I've tried to call something like `const cfg = new pulumi.Config('someName')`, but after that, all the mothods under that class all call for a key (e.g. aValue), but that isn't helpful when wanting all secrets under the logical name.

pulumi.*.yaml

```
  someName:someValue1:
    secure: someSecureValue
  someName:someValue2:
    secure: someOtherSecureValue
```

somefile.ts

```
const cfg = new pulumi.Config('someName')
```

With the given code above, I'm looking for a list of all secrets under `someName`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

From the [docs](https://pulumi.io/reference/programming-model/#config):

> Configuration values are always stored as strings, but can be parsed
>   as richly typed values.
>
> For richer structured data, the config.getObject method can be used to
>   parse JSON values.

For secret values, there are functions `getSecretObject()` and `requireSecretObject()`. For your example, you would do something like

```
pulumi config set --secret someName '{"someValue1": "someSecureValue", "someValue2": "someOtherSecureValue" }'
```

and then read it with

```
const config = new pulumi.Config();
const someName = config.requireSecretObject("someName");
const someValue1 = someName.someValue1;
```

Obviously, you could also use multiple secrets as separate keys in the config file and retrieve them one-by-one with separate `requireSecretObject` calls.

An array would be configured as

```
pulumi config set --secret someName '["someSecureValue", "someOtherSecureValue"]'
```

Comment: Your example shows someName with an array of secrets, but i need multiple `someName:someValue1`, and `someName:someValue2` each with a value to be mapped. Not sure your example illustrates that, or else I'm missing it.

Comment: @shon Edited it to use an object instead of an array

Comment: Thx for updating, after the doc link you provided it pointed me in the right direction, and now that you've updated the answer I'll be voting this one up. Thank you.